# Supervisor throws error with Supervisor NGINX PHP

Tags: php, laravel, docker, supervisord

I am starting a new proyect with Laravel, Docker, Nginx, PHP and I have a problem with supervisor when I add laravel queue / schedule / notifications. If I remove laravel-queue, laravel-notification and laravel-schedule everything work.

Supervisor.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = info

[group:laravel-worker]
priority=999
programs=nginx,php8-fpm,laravel-schedule,laravel-notification,laravel-queue
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
priority=10
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/access.log

[program:php-fpm]
priority=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -R
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-access.log

[program:laravel-schedule]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/schedule.log

[program:laravel-notification]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan notification:worker
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/notification.log

[program:laravel-queue]
numprocs=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/worker.log
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.2-fpm

ARG path=/var/www

WORKDIR $path

#INSTALL DEPENDENCIES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    build-essential \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    locales \
    apt-transport-https \
    wget \
    lsb-release \
    libxml2-dev \
    nginx \
    ca-certificates \
    git \
    nano \
    libonig-dev \
    zip

#Libraries required for Laravel
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    bcmath \
    ctype \
    fileinfo \
    iconv \
    gd \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    xml \
    pcntl

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to $path
COPY --chown=www:www-data . $path

RUN composer install

RUN chmod -R 775 storage && \
    chown -R 1000:www-data storage bootstrap/cache

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w $path/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp ./docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf && \
     cp ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini && \
     cp ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php && \
    touch /var/log/php/errors.log &&  \
    chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

RUN php artisan optimize

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord",  "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

DOCKER COMPOSE

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  rismi-php-nginx:
    container_name: rismi-php-nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - /var/www/vendor
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT:-8080}:80'
```

when I do docker-compose up I get the following exit errors

```
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:21,916 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:21,918 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,922 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 8
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,924 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 9
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,925 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 10
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,927 INFO spawned: 'laravel-notification_00' with pid 11
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,929 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_00' with pid 12
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,931 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_01' with pid 13
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,933 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_02' with pid 14
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,940 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_03' with pid 19
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:22,943 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_04' with pid 24
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,101 INFO exited: laravel-queue_01 (exit status 1; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,111 INFO exited: laravel-schedule_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,126 INFO exited: laravel-notification_00 (exit status 1; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,126 INFO exited: laravel-queue_00 (exit status 1; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,126 INFO exited: laravel-queue_02 (exit status 1; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:23,133 INFO exited: laravel-queue_04 (exit status 1; not expected)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:24,136 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:24,136 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:24,140 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 69
rismi-php-nginx    | 2022-04-08 22:21:24,141 INFO spawned: 'laravel-notification_00' with pid 70
```

Comment: Why are you using Supervisor inside docker? I am assuming this is for a `dev` environment, right? You have a typo, you have `php8-fpm` defined in programs, but you have `[program:php-fpm]`. One last thing, if what you want is just to have `nginx` + `php` + `laravel`, use [`laravel/sail`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail) and [`laravel/horizon`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/horizon) to manage your queues.

Comment: yes, it Is for local environment but I don't use sail and horizon because I am trying to learn docker and this things

Comment: Okay, but using supervisor for this is overkill, you are going to have more issues setting up supervisor (and learning nearling nothing) compared to using `laravel/sail` (check the files it creates and everything around it, you will learn a LOT about docker and that is going to be 100% more useful for you)

Comment: @matiaslauriti Are we not supposed to use supervisor inside docker for a production environment?

Comment: @klido yes, but that is a different case, and you have other solutions